# How do I not lose focus when an application in another workspace opens a dialog?

Tags: gnome

I have applications open in multiple workspaces. I have a Java application running in a different workspace and it opens a dialog window. This causes my current application to lose focus. I do not get the notification that a new window is ready like I usually see in gnome3.

How do I prevent the current application from losing focus when another application opens a dialog?

I am using:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Gnome 3.4.1

Comment: If it's a certain program, opening the dialogs, you could try to quiet that one. Which applications are stealing the focus?